# Jenkins build failing due to docker on GCE

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm a little confused. Jenkins ist giving me this output:
[image]

Docker is definitely installed since I'm using the standard GCE Optimized OS. I have chosen a mulipipline build together with GitHub.

Could somebody please hint me into a direction?

Comment: are you running jenkins inside a docker container ?

Comment: yes I'm  running jenkins inside a docker container

Comment: In that case, docker is not available inside the container, only outside; hence the error

Comment: Ok that is weird since I followed the setup of GCE Jenkins tutorial...